Unexpected Null or Undefined Error When Adding Phone Number in WhatsApp API Setup
I'm encountering an issue while setting up the WhatsApp API. Specifically, when I try to verify my WhatsApp number on the setup page, I receive the following error: Got unexpected null or undefined
Here are the steps I followed and the details of my setup:
WhatsApp API Setup:
Followed the official documentation to set up the WhatsApp Business API.
Adding Phone Number:
Navigated to the WhatsApp API setup page to add and verify my phone number.
Entered the phone number in the required format.
Error Encountered:
Upon submitting the phone number for verification, the system returns the error: Got unexpected null or undefined.

I had the same issue. It seems Meta has a bug with displaying some error messages. Inspect the network and see the request made when you submit your phone number. Check the data you're receiving; there you may find the actual error. In my case, the error was something like "You have too many WhatsApp Business accounts.".

This is what work for me

Log in to your Facebook Business account.
Navigate to the Business Settings.
Select WhatsApp Accounts from the side menu.
Click on your WhatsApp account.
Go to Settings.
Add your phone number in the business Account.

